# How to fix incorrect syntax near 'LOGIN' in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

```
ALTER USER [myuser] WITH LOGIN =[myuser]
```

This query returns error in one of the SQL Server 2005 SP1 installation. Error is

> Incorrect syntax near 'LOGIN'

Comment: What error? Help us help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be a bug in SQL Server 2005.

It is fixed at SP2. So, The the fix is to upgrade it to SP2 or above.

Answer (score 1):

Several things

- You do not need to use `[]` around the user name and login you want.
- You seem to be trying to change the login to itself. That can't be right.

Try this:

```
ALTER USER myuser WITH LOGIN = myLOGIN
```

See the [`ALTER USER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176060.aspx) documentation on MSDN.

Comment: @Rohit - You really don't like to give details, do you? _What_ error message? You understand that you need to replace `myuser` and `myLOGIN` with the correct ones, right? What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
ALTER LOGIN Login WITH name = NewLogin
```

Comment: I want to alter user not login.